# SwiftUI: How can I hide the large space where the title would be set but not the navigation bar?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I've been searching around on SO and I see quite a few posts asking how to hide the title bar, but all answers seem to hide the navigation bar as well. I'm looking for a solution where I can still navigate back but also where the user doesn't see the big white space before the first element rendered in my view.

Thanks

Comment: What is the thing that you call the title bar?

Comment: The giant space underneath the nav bar but before the first element that I've specifically written to render, where the title would go if I set navigationBarTitle

Comment: Have you tried setting the title of each view controller on the stack to `nil`? and can you provide pictures of the current and desired UI?

Comment: `func navigationBarTitle(_ titleKey: LocalizedStringKey) -> some` doesn't accept nil as a value

Comment: @ZackShapiro you should not be setting the navigation bar title directly. You should set the [`title`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621364-title) property of each view controller in the navigation controller stack

Comment: @NoodleOfDeath I'm talking about SwiftUI, not a normal UIViewController. It's different.

Answer (score 7):

Just figured it out. The key here is not only to set the `navigationBarTitle` to `""` but also to set `displayMode: .inline` which sets the title in the nav bar to be an empty string, so you get the nav bar without the big space for a large title below the nav bar

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
       some elements in here...
    }.navigationBarTitle("", displayMode: .inline)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this excellent answer ! [`.navigationBarTitle`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/navigationbartitle(_:)-6p1k7) has now been deprecated, now we can use `.navigationTitle("").navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)` to achieve the same effect